# How can I know if the speed of RAM is the bottleneck rather than CPU speed?

Tags: windows, memory, performance

I have a lot of RAM, 20GB to be precise. However they are not exactly high-end RAMs.Two of them are Kingston 8GB RAMs with 800MHz speed and the other two are some no name brand 2GB RAMs with just 600MHz.

I am having performance problems, even just when using multiple demanding programs. I have slightly overclocked the CPU but that only helped slightly, and only for some things.

I started to suspect that the CPU is fast enough for my needs, but it spends too much time waiting for information to come from the RAM. I am not entirely sure how this is internally handled, but I know that my friends with similar CPUs are not having these problems when running the same games.

So my question is, is there a way to determine that the RAM speed is a bottleneck in the speed of the system? I cannot afford to upgrade my entire system, but I can afford faster RAMs if that would help.

Comment: In my experience, the SPEED of memory (as distinct from how much memory) is much less likely to be your bottleneck than the CPU.  Faster RAM will not likely be very noticeable.

Comment: This sounds more like your CPU/computer is old.  Faster RAM speeds give only the smallest boosts for normal computer operation.   Are you using a HDD?   Nothing speeds up a computer like a SSD.

Comment: only specialized workloads would show any meaningful difference based on ram speed as long as you are comparing to the same generation of RAM, but since you say you have 800MHz and 600MHz mixed, I'm confused as I don't believe there is a JEDEC spec for ram that contains both those speeds. DDR3 supports both 800 (DDR3-1600) and 667 (DDR3-1333), but I don't think any spec supports 600MHz. Keeping in mind that with your ram configuration you are in single-channel mode, you are effectively removing the "Double" from Double Data Rate.  DDR3 is pretty old.

Comment: @FrankThomas - I'd have assumed DDR2 rather than 3 [I don't see a 667 in the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM) for 3, which makes the entire machine potentially 15-20 years old. Any speed gain is going to be unnoticeable, no matter what you do ;)

Comment: Does the machine have SSD or HD? On a machine as old as that appears to be, that will likely be the only area you could make any significant gain.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's using SSD for all the important stuff. I do see CPU running at full load, so it's not waiting for IO. But I am not sure what it would look like if it was waiting for RAM. I don't think OS can tell that a CPU is waiting for RAM rather than actually computing stuff.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica, you can't seperate secondary (disk) IO from RAM IO, because the data from the disk is being loaded into RAM. the CPU can't access the disk any other way.  so if you are not seeing IO lag, you are not experiencing a RAM bottleneck.

Comment: @Tetsujin, you may be quite right. I've been assuming that op was already dividing the freq by 2, since neither class has both 800 and 600, but perhaps he means DDR2-800 and DDR2-667 (so 400MHz and 333MHz per-chip respectively). that would fit. agreed, a system that old can't really be made to be reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are causing your own bottlenecking issues. If you are running two different RAM sticks and one is lower. It will only run at the lowest setting and also where you have two different sizes. Im not 100% but Id say just keep your 2x8's and or upgrade to faster rams sticks.

Comment: this is correct. all the ram in those dimm slots will run at the speed of the slowest stick.